# GROUP BY with CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table jobs with the following structure

```
================================================
| userID  |   jobDate  |  cityID  |  totalCost |
================================================
| 1234    | 2016-04-01 |    1     |     200    |
| 1234    | 2016-04-21 |    1     |     800    |
| 1234    | 2016-08-03 |    1     |     2000   |
| 1234    | 2016-12-01 |    1     |     300    |
| 1234    | 2017-02-01 |    1     |     500    |
================================================
```

I want the month to be transposed into columns.

**Expected Output:**

```
========================================================
| userID | April 2016 | May 2016 | .... | January 2017 |
========================================================
|  1234  |    1000    |   0      | .... |     500      |
========================================================
```

**My query:**

```
 SELECT u.userID, u.userFullName, ci.cityName,
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'April 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'April 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'April 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'April 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'May 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'May 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'May 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'May 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'June 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'June 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'June 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'June 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'July 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'July 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'July 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'July 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'August 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'August 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'August 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'August 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'September 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'September 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'September 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'September 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'October 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'October 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'October 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'October 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'November 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'November 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'November 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'November 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'December 2016' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'December 2016 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'December 2016' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'December 2016 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'January 2017' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'January 2017 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'January 2017' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'January 2017 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'February 2017' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'February 2017 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'February 2017' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'February 2017 Spends',

    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'March 2017' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName))
        ELSE '-'
    END AS 'March 2017 Services',
    CASE
        WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'March 2017' THEN SUM(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'March 2017 Spends'
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.categoryID = j.categoryID
LEFT JOIN supercategories s ON s.supercategoryID = c.supercategoryID
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userID = j.userID
LEFT JOIN city ci ON ci.cityID = j.cityID
WHERE j.jobStatus = 'completed' AND
      DATE(j.jobDate) BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY u.userID
```

**Query Output:**

```
========================================================
| userID | April 2016 | May 2016 | .... | January 2017 |
========================================================
|  1234  |    1500    |   0      | .... |      0       |
========================================================
```

All the rows are getting transposed into the first occurrence column. If I add `GROUP BY MONTHNAME(jobDate)` then I get multiple rows per user. Can you help what can be wrong here?

Comment: This kind of table pivot need dynamic sql query. Check http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html.

Comment: When you have to scroll to read the query, it's high time to minimize the problem!

Comment: Those are case expressions, not statements.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application level code.

Comment: I am running queries directly to generate raw results for analysis. This isn't for any system or webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just forgot to put sum on the case , see the first two months,
you must put sum since you have multiple records per month (you can see you have two rows during April 2016

```
     SELECT u.userID, u.userFullName, ci.cityName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'April 2016' THEN CONCAT(c.categoryName, ' ', s.supercategoryName)
        END) AS 'April 2016 Services',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CONCAT(MONTHNAME(j.jobDate), ' ', YEAR(j.jobDate)) = 'April 2016' THEN ROUND(j.totalCost + j.discountReceived)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'April 2016 Spends',
    FROM jobs j
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.categoryID = j.categoryID
    LEFT JOIN supercategories s ON s.supercategoryID = c.supercategoryID
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userID = j.userID
    LEFT JOIN city ci ON ci.cityID = j.cityID
    WHERE j.jobStatus = 'completed' AND
          DATE(j.jobDate) BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY u.userID
```

Comment: Adding SUM() gives an error - `Invalid use of group function`. For April 2016 Services, the `CONCAT` function produces string while the April 2016 Spends already has a `SUM` done within the CASE statement.

Comment: Figured out the issue, the `GROUP_CONCAT` function needed to be applied on the `CASE ` statement. I can't seem to edit your answer, kindly make the changes so that I can approve it.

Comment: i forgot to remove the sum inside the case, and i remove the sum from the group_concat